# C++ header inclusion

Tags: c++, header

Although I include the header file of a class in my implementation like:

```
#include<Utility.h>
```

I still get fatal error: Utility.h: No such file or directory

Is there any idea why? Utility.h and Utility.cpp in my current project folder

Comment: Is that header in your system headers directory?

Comment: Is it a header that you wrote? Try `"Utility.h"`

Comment: Actually why doesn't it accept <> case instead of "" case.

Comment: for <> vs "", check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename

Comment: Does your compiler looks in the directory where the header is?

Comment: If you tell your compiler to look in your current directly, such as with `-I .` or `/I .` (depending on your compiler), then it will add the current directory to the `<>` search list.

Comment: @AvbAvb You people don't read beginner C++ tutorials, do you.

Comment: Did you want the standard C++ header 'utility' which has std::pair and the like? In which case you should `#include <utility>` without the .h EDIT: I just reread the question and clearly you didn't...

Comment: Add the header file path to your compile command using -I <path>

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "Utility.h"
```

This is the way to include a .h file that you wrote and is in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <file>
This variant is used for system header files. It searches for a file named file in a standard list of system directories. 

#include "file"
This variant is used for header files of your own program. It searches for a file named file first in the directory containing the current file, then in the quote directories and then the same directories used for <file>.
```